# Pandas - vectorizing convoluted update

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains 3 columns: `path`, `tags` and `column1`, where `tags` is a `list of strings` and `column1` has `boolean` values.
Now I want to group them by `path` using regular expression which depends on part on row's `path` value. Namely, each row has unique value and i want to group them with other files that contain *similar* `path`.
Then, if all rows in this group meet some condition (in this example, there can't be more than 5 such items), all rows' columns are modified.

```
def has_to_change(df):
  if len(df) > 5:
      return True
  else:
      False

def add_tag_to_tags(row):
  if 'tag' not in row['tags']:
      row['tags'].append('tag')
  return row

if __name__ == '__main__':

  pattern =  r'some regex'
  regex =  re.compile(pattern)

  df = pd.read_csv(df_path)

  for index, row in df.iterrows():
      file_name = row['path']
      matches = regex.search(file_name)
      org_path = matches.group('some regex group') #get a match from this row's path

      matching_rows = df[df['path'].str.contains(org_path+'(\.xml|\.txt)')] #find all rows that contain this file name but with some difference, say, another extentions xml or txt

      if has_to_change(matching_rows): #if condition met, change it's vale and save back to dataframe
          #i keep loop here because i want to overwrite row with the same index (it was originally a bit more complex)
          for inner_index, augmented_row in matching_rows.iterrows():
              augmented_row['column'] = True
              augmented_row.apply(add_tag_to_tags, axis=1)
              df.iloc[inner_index] = augmented_row
```

**Can such a code be somehow vectorized**? It's super slow but I can't find any way to:

1. create groups by regular expression
2. check value for each such group as a whole
3. and only then update these groups

**Example data**

```
      path,                              tags,             column1
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.jpg,       ['tag1'],         False
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.xml,       ['tag1'],         False
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.txt,       ['tag1', 'tag1'], False
/mnt/train_image_png_1221_aug_1245_5.jpg,['tag1'],         False
/mnt/000000306488_aug_9203_1.jpg,        ['tag1'],         False
/mnt/000000391768_aug_20250_1.jpg,       ['tag1'],         False
/mnt/1561887652.9493463_aug_1462_0.jpg,  ['tag1'],         True
```

After update:

```
      path,                              tags,                   column1
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.jpg,       ['tag1','tag'],         True
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.xml,       ['tag1','tag'],         True
/mnt/000000386703_aug_13237_0.txt,       ['tag1','tag1', 'tag'], True
/mnt/train_image_png_1221_aug_1245_5.jpg,['tag1'],               False
/mnt/000000306488_aug_9203_1.jpg,        ['tag1'],               False
/mnt/000000391768_aug_20250_1.jpg,       ['tag1'],               False
/mnt/1561887652.9493463_aug_1462_0.jpg,  ['tag1'],               True
```

First 3 rows have `tag` value added to `tags` column and column value is changed to `True` because they share `path` value that is caught by regular expression `find all rows that have similar path` (so it's dependant on row's `path`)

Comment: Add example data and expected output please

Comment: Your question is quite general so I will point you to a [general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4909087) that should hopefully help you find the right functions to replace the call to iterrows().

Comment: this general answer does not answer my question of how to group rows by regular expression that depends on row's value.